# Average Velocity Question (isolation?)

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, time, velocity

So there is this question i've been having trouble with for the past hour. It involved a child going down a ramp on a sled at and angle theta with a total system of mass. accelerates down a hill of length L during a time interval delta t.
(this is literally all the question gives you, other than a really simple diagram which only indicates where the 0 is located)

So far I've figured out that a = gsin0.

The question it's asking me is the magnitude of the child's velocity is.
(choices)
The correct choice is e which is sqrt(gLsin0/2) 
How do they end up with this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using a zero as a theta is confusing. If you don’t know MathJax yet and can’t write $\sin{\theta}$, I suggest just writing it out as “sin(theta)”.

Comment: Your title indicates that you actually want the *average* speed, but your explanation makes it sound like you want the speed at the bottom of the hill.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you know the acceleration due to gravity is g ($9.81 \frac{m}{s^2}$).

Next you know, ignoring friction on the slide and air resistance, all masses have the same vertical acceleration g in a gravitational field.

Then you know the acceleration of the child is as a function of g,  $a=gsin$.

Next, you know from kinematics that the distance traveled, which is $L$, is given by

$L=\frac{at^2}{2}$

From that you can calculate the time it takes the child to go distance $L$. Then finally you can calculate the velocity from

$v=at$

The answer they gave you is probably just a combination of these steps.

Hope this helps.